# Define a variable that can be referred in frontend and backend

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I have a mean-stack website. In the root, there is a file `.env` where I can define variables like `SENDGRID_API_KEY=xxxxx`, so that it can be referred in the **backend** by `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY`.

I am wondering if there is a way to define a variable somewhere that can be referred in both **backend** and **frontend**.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply serve it in a global variable when rendering views in script metas.

Comment: maybe any details?

Comment: what server side language are you using ? What's your stack for rendering views ?

Comment: when you render the html for the views render in the page, possibly in head section something like <script> var myvar = process.env.var; </script> and retrieve from angular with myAngularVar = window.myvar.

Comment: Are you sure `process.env.var` can be used in head section? I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.